# How to assign a Cython object instance to another object

Tags: python, cython

Code below seems to have difficulty assigning a Cython object as an attribute. It generates the error: "AttributeError: 'parameters.Parameters' object has no attribute 'alpha'. How can this be fixed?

File1:
#parameters.pyx

```
from parameters cimport Parameters
cdef class Parameters(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.alpha = 1.0
```

File2:
#parameters.pxd

```
cdef class Parameters:
    cdef float alpha
```

File3:
#run.pyx

```
class Run(object):
    def __init__(self,parameters):
        self.parameters = parameters
        print (self.parameters.alpha)
```

File4:
#model.pyx

```
import run
from parameters cimport Parameters

def simple():
    parameters = Parameters()
    run_instance = run.Run(parameters)
```

SetupFile

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(["*.py","*.pyx"], include_path=["."],
language="c++")
    
)
```